# Next.js, debugging server-side code with chrome devtools. Breakpoints are ignored and console output does not go to chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, next.js

I'm following this guide.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging

And I'm trying to use the chrome debugger to debug the server part of a next js application (without using VS Code).

I have started next as per the instructions in that article.

The problem that I get is that I can connect to the next js server using chrome://inspect and the console output from the next application will say that the debugger is connected. The application shows up in the list on the chrome://inspect page and I can connect to it. I can also pause the application using the chrome devtools.

What I can't do is either have the application stop using a "debugger;" statement, the application will simply blow straight through the breakpoint as if it isn't there. It will also show console output in the console window I used to start the next js application and not in the chrome debugger window.

I tried setting different things like verbose output etc in chrome devtools, but it didn't do anything.

As an experiment I started a clean Next JS application with linting and Typescript disabled, but I still get the same issue.

I also tried it using a basic expressJS application as well as a simple node console application and in both of those cases it worked fine. So it seems to be a problem specific to next JS. But the docs don't mention anything.

Comment: FYI: This issue is also open on github https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48767

Comment: I seem to have this problem too. chrome://inspect allows me to open a window on my server-side code and set breakpoints. But I can't find a way to then "reload" the window and "activate" them